# react native build excuted, failed for task ':appcenter-push:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

i have problem for exec build to apk from react native.

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':appcenter-push:verifyReleaseResources'.
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

how can fix it?

Comment: It's really hard to get about the issue. Can you please share some more details?

Comment: did you use react-native link cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know the problem with a few information.

It looks caused by appcenter-push settings.

1. Make to use same SDK versions.

   android/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Reapply appcenter-push to your android.

   Official docs.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/react-native-android
3. Remove `appcenter-push` from your code and rebuild.